# How to properly map tiled texture with non-uniform scale?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

Blender Internal here. Texture is scaled to maintain circle as circle. And has offset to put it (circle) in the center.

With *Generated (cube)* mapping it is almost good, except one moment where tiles do not follow each other in one direction.

[image]

With *UV map* I can rotate those parts to match direction, but everything else is messed.

[image]

I've tried to use *min/max Crop* settings with no luck (by the way, does Crop actually scale rather than crop?)
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible; either texture should be square or cube should be parallelepiped (and even then 2 sides will loose proportions). Crop settings won't help here - they crop, not change ratio of the texture.

Comment: I don't know what you're using for the original texture image but I've had similar problems and have simply taken each individual face in the UV editor and positioned and scaled until it looked right.  In cases where the "repeat" comes into view, I've gone back to the image file and increased it's canvas size, saved that as another image and used it on the errant surface(s).

Comment: Edgel3D, problem is that I have many cubes with videoclip textures, and their ratio is 16:9, so it is a bit of work.